# Angular with repeating component and their logic

Tags: angular

I am new to Stackoverflow and as well as Angular too, so apologies for appropriate question format.

My question is related to Angular repeating component. Let's say I have a Jokes component and Joke Component.

### jokes.componet.html

```
<div>
    <joke *ngFor="let joke of jokesBox" [oneJoke]="joke"></joke>

</div>
```

### joke.componet.ts

```
    <div>JokeTitle</div>
    <div>Joke Body</div>
    <div><span>Update</span> <span>Delete</span></div>
```

WHAT I DID IN JOKE COMPONENT

....several imports
.....injected service dependencies
..... performed Inbuilt Observable subscriptions
....wrote methods for update and delete

So, My question is about this Joke Component which is getting iterated over an array Jokes. Does writing some imports and injecting services in Joke Component will cause any performance or memory leak issue.

Comment: No, why would it?

Comment: I thought It would be as single Joke Component itself will be repeated many times and Joke Component contains some DI and Subscriptions so they will be repeated too

Comment: Yes, each Joke component will have its own reference to an injected service, so what? That's not a memory leak. That's just an object having a reference to another object. Subscriptions might be another matter, but without any code, we  can't tell much.

Comment: I am using httpClient for fetching some more info based on the Joke Data

Comment: **but without any code, we can't tell much.**

Comment: @RohitSharma http client itself unsubscribe when the fetching completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concerned about performance,then you have to analyze the factors which might deteriorate your app's performance. Since performance is a very vast topic and any small thing might reduce your app's performance. Let's have some pieces here and try to understand few :

First of all, webpack(module-bundler) will build your app. With Webpack following things will happen :

a) **Tree Shaking** : So no matter how many packages you have, only the files you have imported will be considered, this happens at build phase so no impact on performance at runtime, all the third party packages will go in Vendor.js and your code in main.js.

b) **Bundling & Minification** : You app will be minified and bundled in order to serve with less latency and less no. of server calls respectively. Scripts, Images, Assets all will be bundled.

Now, since you have nested child components, one more key factor would be **Change Detection Strategy** since **Accessing the DOM tree is always expensive**

We have "default" and "OnPush" Change detection strategy in Angular, now with your problem if you have multiple nested components and with any change it triggers cycle for nested components as well and sometimes you want those changes to be reflected, only when the state is mutated, in that case you need to use OnPush Strategy.

[Mutation](https://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aa)

[Change Detection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

[Webpack](https://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/)

There is a lot, when we ask for performance review, without proper code none can tell for eg. you might have multiple subscriptions for the same observable, instead of sharing those, so for the sake of brevity and to answer your question, have touched with few insights.